# How to display records from two tables in codeigniter by $row[ ]

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
<?php
    function cash_wallet_ajax($from_date='',$to_date='')
    {
        $aColumns = array( 'w.trans_date', 'd.trans_comment');
        $sTable = "tbl_ewallet w, tbl_deposit_request d";
        $sWhere = "WHERE (w.customerid = 1 and w.status=4) or (d.user_id = 2 and d.date!=3)"; 
    
        $print_query = $sQuery = " SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ".str_replace(" , ", " ", implode(", ", $aColumns))." FROM  $sTable $sWhere ";
        $rResult = $this->db->query($sQuery);  
        /* Data set length after filtering */
        $sQuery = " SELECT FOUND_ROWS() ";
        $rResultFilterTotal = $this->db->query( $sQuery ); 
        $aResultFilterTotal = $rResultFilterTotal->result_array(); 
        $iFilteredTotal = $aResultFilterTotal[0];
        /* Total data set length */
        $sQuery = " SELECT COUNT(".$sIndexColumn.") FROM   $sTable ";
        $rResultTotal = $this->db->query( $sQuery );   
        $aResultTotal = $rResultTotal->result_array();   
        $iTotal = $aResultTotal[0];
        $output = array(
        //"sEcho" => intval($_POST['sEcho']),
        "iTotalRecords" => $iTotal,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords" => $iFilteredTotal,
        "ksQuery" => $print_query,
        "aaData" => array()
        );      
        $i=1;           
        $aRows = $rResult->result_array();
        $srno=1;
        foreach ($aRows as $aRow) 
        { 
            $row = array();             
            
            $row[] = $aRow['trans_date']; //problem here
            $row[] = $aRow['trans_comment']; //problem here
            
            $output['aaData'][] = $row;
        }
        echo json_encode( $output );
    }
?>
```

Screenshot :[image]

**UPDATE :**

I try to split two foreach loop for the two difference tables :

```
$aRows = $rResult->result_array();
$aRows2 = $rResult->result_array();
foreach ($aRows as $aRow) 
{ 
    $row = array();             
    $row[] = $aRow['trans_date']; //problem here
    $output['aaData'][] = $row;
}

foreach ($aRows2 as $aRow2) 
{ 
    $row2 = array();             
    $row2[] = $aRow['trans_comment']; //problem here
    $output['aaData2'][] = $row2;
}
echo json_encode( $output );
```

But why it show output of first foreach loop only?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by using `AS` . The logic behind is either show record of 1st table or 2nd table, don't show record of both at the same row.

```
$aColumns = array( 'w.trans_date As p_date', 'd.trans_comment As p_comment');

$aRows = $rResult->result_array();
foreach ($aRows as $aRow) 
{ 
    $row = array();             
    $row[] = $aRow['p_date']; 
    $row2[] = $aRow['p_comment']; 
    $output['aaData'][] = $row;
}
```